# ODBC data provider is not listed in data source dialog

Tags: asp.net, db2, odbc, datasource, dataprovider

I work on asp.net mvc project and have database on Db2.

I am trying to connect to database using ODBC data provider.

But an ODBC data provider is not listed in data source dialog box.

I am trying to model database tables that already exists in Db2
[that is what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f6vb.png)

Comment: What have you installed to connect to Db2?  Can you see the data source in the odbcad32 gui ?

Comment: What happens when you try selecting "Other", and continuing?

Comment: Is selects .net framework data provider for sql server